# Capistrano bundler:install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my rails app into an EC2 instance using Capistrano 3.0. I'm now stack with the following output which appears when running "cap production deploy" or "cap production bundler:install".

```
DEBUG [5b379979] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/app/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/app/current'" 1>&2; false; fi on ec2-75-101-200-185.compute-1.amazonaws.com
DEBUG [5b379979] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/app/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/app/current'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [5b379979] Finished in 2.285 seconds command successful.
 INFO [f15c9f08] Running /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /var/www/app/current/Gemfile --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --deployment --verbose --binstubs /var/www/billtune/shared/bin --without development test on ec2-75-101-200-185.compute-1.amazonaws.com
DEBUG [f15c9f08] Command: cd /var/www/app/current && /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /var/www/app/current/Gemfile --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --deployment --verbose --binstubs /var/www/app/shared/bin --without development test
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    bundle
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    
cap aborted!
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/Users/shaimo-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => bundler:install
```

When ssh-ing into the server and running the same command (`cd /var/www/app/current && /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /var/www/app/current/Gemfile --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --deployment --verbose --binstubs /var/www/app/shared/bin --without development test`) all seems to be ok.

Answer (score 5):

The lines

```
DEBUG [f15c9f08] Command: cd /var/www/app/current && /usr/bin/env bundle --gemfile /var/www/app/current/Gemfile --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --deployment --verbose --binstubs /var/www/app/shared/bin --without development test
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    bundle
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [f15c9f08]
```

Indicate that bundler isn't found, or isn't installed. Capistrano (as documented here http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/) runs in a **non-login, non-interactive shell**.

I would guess that bundler is installed in a special path, or that you are using rvm, chruby, or rbenv. And that these things aren't being initialized as they are when you SSH into the box, because of the non-login, non-interactive session that Capistrano is using.

The solution is to use either the `capistrano-{rvm,chruby,rbenv}` gem which suits your envrironment as documented in the `Capfile`.

If you are not using one of those version managers, try this:

```
ssh me@theserver 'which bundler'
```

Probably you will see no output (more on why at the link above), solve that, and Capistrano will work.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was indeed with the *non-interactive shell*.

Eventually I had to add the following line to `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

In case others get into similar issues, I will add that I also had to map the `rake` command so it would work properly. Had to add the following line to my `deploy.rb` file:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use capistrano-rbenv gem to manage your ror env

1. add `gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0' to your` gemfile
2. uncomment `require 'capistrano/rbenv'` in your capfile; if `capistrano/bundler` commented, uncomment it also
3. set the rbenv_ruby variable `set :rbenv_ruby, '2.0.0-p247'` in your deploy file

then all set!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the following code to ~/.bashrc:

```
export RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm bit late to answer the question, but it might help some user like me.

If you're using `rbenv` then set the default environment of your `rbenv` by adding below line in `deploy.rb`

> `set :default_env, { path: "~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }`

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle` executable is missing from system or its PATH is not known to the shell.

Check below test:

system can find `perl` executable:

```
# /usr/bin/env perl
^C   << I did CTRL+C as perl was expecitng me to put some code
```

now, my system can't find `perlyo` executable and throws the error:

```
# /usr/bin/env perlyo
/usr/bin/env: perlyo: No such file or directory
```

Above error is similar to what you get for `/usr/bin/env bundle` which is:

```
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    bundle
DEBUG [f15c9f08]    : No such file or directory
```

check whether system knows about `bundle` by running below command:

```
# which bundle
# whereis bundle
```

If it can't find with above commands, then check whether `bundle` at all exists on system as below:

```
# updatedb
# locate bundle
```

If you find the `bundle`, then add its `path` accordingly so that your shell can recognize it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @zpieslak said:

add this in ~/.bashrc:

```
if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

Before this line:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```